# I am new to C# and Unity and cannot figure these errors in my script out after looking for hours

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been working with my group all day to figure out some errors with our script that we wrote to not only move the ship side to side but also tilt it as it moves. Unfortunately after working for many many hours and seemingly getting closer to making our script work we cannot figure out why these errors are popping up and what we're missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated by the three of us.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControllerV2 : MonoBehaviour
{
  Rigidbody rb;
  [Range(0,20)] public float speed = 2.0f;
  public float constant = 1f;
  float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
  float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

  void Start()
  {
    var smooth = 2.0;
    var tiltAngle = 30.0;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb.freezeRotation = false;
  }

  void Update()
  {
    var tiltAroundZ;
    var tiltAroundX;

    tiltAroundZ = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * tiltAngle * constant;
    tiltAroundX = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * tiltAngle * constant;
    if(Input.GetKey(Keycode.A)||Input.GetKey(Keycode.D))
    {
      while(Input.GetKey(Keycode.A)||Input.GetKey(Keycode.D))
      {
        if(constant <= 10f)
        {
          constant *= 1.1f;
          float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
          tiltAroundZ = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * tiltAngle * constant;
          tiltAroundX = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * tiltAngle * constant;
          Rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical) * speed);
          var target = Quaternion.Euler (tiltAroundX, 0, tiltAroundZ);
        }
        else if(constant >= 10.1f)
        {
          continue;
        }
      }
      while(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)||Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
      {
        if(constant <= 10f)
        {
          constant *= 1.1f;
          tiltAroundX = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * tiltAngle * constant;
          tiltAroundZ = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * tiltAngle * constant;
          tiltAroundX = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * tiltAngle * constant;
          Rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical) * speed);
          var target = Quaternion.Euler (tiltAroundX, 0, tiltAroundZ);
        }
        else if(constant >= 10.1f)
        {
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is our console:
[Unity Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0SXh.png)

Comment: you have declared variables in different scope and trying to access in different scope..and you cannot access non static members of a class without the object of the same class

Comment: also KeyCode is missing a Capital C.

Comment: You cant use var type without initializing it. change them to float if you dont want to initialize them or declare them at the same time you give them a value. You cant do `Rigidbody.AddForce` because Rigidbody is a class and  AddForce is not a static function.Rigidbody is not a reference . use the variable rb instead.

Comment: You should use Visual Studio for programming. You would have noticed these errors a lot faster this way

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't use

   ```
   var tiltAroundZ;
   ```

   without initializing it right away. Basically exactly what the errors tells you. Simply change it to

   ```
   float tiltAroundZ = 0f;
   ```
2. You declared `tiltAngle` as local variable within `Start`

   ```
   private void Start()
   {
       ...
       var tiltAngle = 30.0;
       ...
   }
   ```

   so it won't be available for any other method. Rather make it a field in the class. You most probably then also want it to be a `float` not a `double`

   ```
   private float tiltAngle = 30.0f;
   ```
3. `Keycode` is a typo: It is a **capital** `C` in [`KeyCode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html)
4. Your `Rigidbody` instance is stored in a field called `rb` so it should be

   ```
   rb.AddForce(new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical) * speed);
   ```

---

Some more things

5. Both initializations

   ```
   float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
   float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
   ```

make no sense at this point. They will always be `0` anyway since at app start there is no input handled yet.

6. another **huge issue** in your code namely this line

   ```
   while(Input.GetKey(Keycode.A)||Input.GetKey(Keycode.D))
   ```

You almost **never** want any `while` loop in Unity - especially not in the `Update` method!

This will simply freeze your Application/The entire Unity Editor until the `continue` condition is met since `Input.GetKey` will never change its value within one frame!

I don't really understand what your goal with this is but instead of keeping calling `AddForce` repeatedly you should rather call it only once right away with the correct amount of force instead.

You also never reset `constant` so after reaching `>= 10` you ignore any user input ...

---

The errors from `CameraTitle` can't be fixed here without you showing that code.